# Minimum 6 characters regex

Tags: regex

I'm looking for regex which checks for at least 6 characters, regardless of which type of character.

Comment: You are asking for one of the simplest regular expressions possible - you clearly have made no attempt to find out by yourself.

Comment: Well, "all characters" is a bit unclear: do you consider various accented letters (e.g. `Ȃ`) as characters, or is the basic set of 26 Latin letters A-Z sufficient?

Comment: Related: [Setting a minimum/maximum character count for any character using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10518979/3357935)

Comment: Are you _sure_ you need a regex? In most programming languages, you can just look at `myString.length` or so to determine that.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

This match 6 or more any chars but newline:

```
/^.{6,}$/
```

Comment: This is accepting null also.. How to avoid it? Tried "regexFormat": "^(\\S{4,10})$" in JavaScript but not working.

Comment: @PranjalSuccessena: What do you mean by `null`? Using javascript, you don't need to double escape, have a try with: `regex = /^\S{4,10}$/;`

Answer (score 34):

If I understand correctly, you need a regex statement that checks for at least 6 characters (letters & numbers)?

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}/
```

Comment: yes but it can be special characthers etc.. all types but 6 letters filter.

Comment: If you want any, you can just do this (not advisable though):

/.{6,}/

Answer (score 8):

Something along the lines of this?

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtUsername" runat="server" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    id="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Field not valid!"
    ControlToValidate="txtUsername"
    ValidationExpression="[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}" />
```

Comment: This does not includes speacial characters such as !@#% or any as the question demands