# Setting a minimum/maximum character count for any character using a regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will be used on a text box to validate its contents to see if it is between 1 and 35. The characters within the text box can be anything: numeric, alpha, punctuation, white space, etc. Here is what I have so far:

```
^[:;,\-@0-9a-zA-Zâéè'.\s]{1,35}$
```

As you can see, I have to list out all characters. Is there an easier way to say "all" characters?

Comment: Don't use a regex to enforce nothing besides length.  Just check the length.

Answer (score 75):

Like this: `.`

The `.` means any character except newline (which sometimes is but often isn't included, check your regex flavour).

You can rewrite your expression as `^.{1,35}$`, which should match any line of length 1-35.

Comment: In many regex engines, `.` does *not* match a newline, but does match any other character (unless you use a flag to tell it otherwise).  In that case, you might try something like `[\s\S]` (either a space character or a nonspace character).

Comment: I would expect `echo "Hello" | grep "^.{1,35}$"` to match, but it doesn't... any idea why?

Comment: The default `grep` regexp flavour, `--basic-regexp`, interprets various otherwise special characters literally, and their special behaviour requires escaping. `echo "Hello" | grep --basic-regexp "^.\{1,35\}$"` and `echo "Hello" | grep --extended-regexp "^.{1,35}$"` work.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to set a minimum of 1 count and no maximum length,

```
^.{1,}$
```

Comment: `^.+$` is simpler for this.

Comment: While this is helpful for some users (including me), it does not answer the original question.

Comment: @Melebius you are right. This is for users who land on this page but need not necessarily have the requirement as mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 24):

It's usually the metacharacter `.` when not inside a character class.

So use `^.{1,35}$`. However, *dot* does not include newlines unless the dot-all modifier is applied against it.

You can use `^[\S\s]{1,35}$` without any modifiers, and this includes newlines as well.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, `.` (dot) would match any character. Use:

```
^.{1,35}$
```

Answer (score 6):

If you also want to match newlines, then you might want to use `"^[\s\S]{1,35}$"` (depending on the regex engine).  Otherwise, as others have said, you should used `"^.{1,35}$"`