# minimum length of characters in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex: `^([0-9]{1,4}(\ -?)){3}[0-9]{1,4}$`

As it is, it matches `1234`

I would like to force to match only on 6 or more digits (ie. not including dashes) eg. 1234 12 or 12 1 123 or 1 1 123 1 or 1-12-12-2222 or 1-123 2 2 etc.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: I believe `{6,}` is minimum of 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum 6 characters regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166738/minimum-6-characters-regex-expression)

Comment: Why do you escape the hyphen (`-`)? It is not a special character in `RegExp`.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn - that is not what I'm asking

Comment: What about `str.replace(/-/g, '').length >= 6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead to assert presence of at least 6 digits:

```
/^(?=(?:\D*\d){6})(?:\d{1,4}[ -]?){3}\d{1,4}$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jBXgyE/1)

Here `(?=(?:\D*\d){6})` is a positive lookahead that asserts true when at least 6 digits are present with 0 or more non-digits in between.